# android httpget read from a website to sqlite columns

Tags: android, sqlite

I have this line of text:

```
id:1234 dateandtime: 03/10/2011 14:30 firstnumber:2222 secondnumber:3333 centernumber: 4444
refrancenumber:5555 webaddress: www.example.com
```

And I'm using this code to read it off my website that I have for testing

```
//Encode and set entity
postMethod.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, HTTP.UTF_8));
//Execute and get the response - remove all html tag
addressString = hc.execute(postMethod, res).replaceAll("<(.|\n)*?>","");
```

My problem is that this code reads it as one paragraph I want to separate them so I can insert each one of them in its own column in an sqlite database.

Note: the `1234`, `03/10/2011 14:30`, `2222`, `3333`, `4444`, `5555`, and the `www.example.com` each will be stored in a separate sqlite column.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I recommend to use JSON structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend reading about the `String.split(String regularExpression)` function: [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: thanks a lot for the help but is there an example on how to use the String.split(String regularExpression) function

Comment: @Moe: you could either read the documentation I already linked in my answer, or you could start here: http://www.google.com/search?q=android+string+split+example